# rest service adapter support and authorisation

Tags: spring-integration

I need to call a rest service using HTTPS as part of my SI flow. I may additionally have to send user name and password as headers to authorize my access. What are the tools available to configure this in spring integration?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS should "just work".

You can set headers with a header enricher and set `mapped-request-headers` on the outbound gateway to ensure your headers are mapped.

For more sophistication, you can customize the `RestTemplate` and inject it into the outbound endpoint.

See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/1.2.x/spring-xd-messagebus-spi/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/integration/bus/RabbitManagementUtils.java#L46) for an example of configuring the underlying request factory.